# Golang: acronym of given sentence

Tags: go

How to find, given a sentence, the acronym of that sentence using GO programming language. For example, “Hello, world!” becomes “HW”. So far I have tried splitting the sentence:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "os"
)
func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Enter text: ")
    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Print(strings.Split(text," "))
    fmt.Print(strings.Index(text, ))
}
```

1. Took input from the user
2. Split on the occurrence of white space.
3. What next?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you have split the strings you need to append the first letter of each word to your result string.

```
text := "Hello World"
words := strings.Split(text, " ")

res := ""

for _, word := range words {
    res = res + string([]rune(word)[0])
}

fmt.Println(res)
```

Note that you might need to add some checks to catch the case if the input is empty which results in a `[""]` from `strings.Split`.

Comment: But I could not understand the logic.. the meaning the this particular code string([]rune(word)[0])

Comment: @RISHIKHANNA Which specific part do you not understand?

Comment: string([]rune(word)[0])

Comment: @RISHIKHANNA I see, it's the way how to access individual characters of a string in Go. For more information check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15018545/893693) question and the links it leads to.

Comment: You actually don't need to convert to an array or runes before converting to a string

Comment: @openwonk Did you check the comment to your answer?

Comment: That's fair.  I don't often have to think of acronyms in non-ASCII terms... See updated answer and comments in code.  I'd still recommend applying `strings.Title("...")` to ensure capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with first answer, but slightly different implementation; be sure to `import "strings"` at beginning of your code:

```
text := "holur stál fyrirtæki" // fake manufacturer, "hollow steel company"
words := strings.Split(text, " ")

res := ""

for _, word := range words {
    // Convert to []rune before string to preserve UTF8 encoding
    // Use "Title" from "strings" package to ensure capitalization of acronym
    res += strings.Title(string([]rune(word)[0]))
}

fmt.Println(res) // => "HSF"
```

Comment: The problem is by using `string(word[0])` you dropped support for utf-8. That's why the other response is using `[]rune(word)[0]`. Compare with greek perspective http://play.golang.org/p/bkk_XkhtJr

Comment: That's fair.  I don't often have to think of acronyms in non-ASCII terms... See updated answer and comments in code.   I'd still recommend applying `strings.Title("...")` to ensure capitalization.